# How to search into nested JSON by values with Python

Tags: python, json, nested

In the following JSON object (that I can rewrite if it is easier) I need to seach the sshPort for id="Talend" and envs.id="DEV" and sshServer="jardev0"

I've tried using Pandas but it flattens the nested JSON objets, so I have to create 3 intermediate Pandas objets and search 3 times into them.

I would expect easier syntax, something like " [x.id=="talend" && x[envs].id=="DEV" && x|envs].sshServer="jardev0"]."sshPort"

```
[
    {
        "id": "talend",
        "envs":
            [
            {"id":"DEV",
             "lServeurs" :
                 [
                    {"sshServer":"jardev0", "sshPort":"20022","sshUser":"talend"},
                    {"sshServer":"jardev01","sshPort":"20022","sshUser":"talend"}
                 ]
            },
            {"id": "PROD",
             "lServeurs" :
                [
                    {"sshServer": "jardprd01", "sshPort": "20023","sshUser":"talend"}
                ]
            }
            ]
    },
    {
        "id": "eprel",
        "envs":
            [
                {"id": "DEV",
                 "lServeurs" :
                     [
                         {"sshServer": "jardev0",  "sshPort": "20024", "sshUser":"eprel"},
                         {"sshServer": "jardev01", "sshPort": "20025", "sshUser":"eprel"}
                     ]
                 },
                {"id": "PROD",
                 "lServeurs" :
                     [
                         {"sshServer": "jardprd01", "sshPort": "20026","sshUser":"eprel"}
                     ]
                 }
            ]
    }
]
```

this should return "20022"

Comment: try iterating through loops like json_data[0]['envs'][0]['id']. Have to leave for home, will see tomorrow if you still need help. json_data is above data only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using nested list comprehensions (3 nested iterators are very clumsy though):

```
import json

jsn = """[
    {
        "id": "talend",
        "envs":
            [
            {"id":"DEV",
             "lServeurs" :
                 [
                    {"sshServer":"jardev0", "sshPort":"20022","sshUser":"talend"},
                    {"sshServer":"jardev01","sshPort":"20022","sshUser":"talend"}
                 ]
            },
            {"id": "PROD",
             "lServeurs" :
                [
                    {"sshServer": "jardprd01", "sshPort": "20023","sshUser":"talend"}
                ]
            }
            ]
    },
    {
        "id": "eprel",
        "envs":
            [
                {"id": "DEV",
                 "lServeurs" :
                     [
                         {"sshServer": "jardev0",  "sshPort": "20024", "sshUser":"eprel"},
                         {"sshServer": "jardev01", "sshPort": "20025", "sshUser":"eprel"}
                     ]
                 },
                {"id": "PROD",
                 "lServeurs" :
                     [
                         {"sshServer": "jardprd01", "sshPort": "20026","sshUser":"eprel"}
                     ]
                 }
            ]
    }
]"""

x = json.loads(jsn)


targetPorts = [server['sshPort'] for envsKV in x for env in envsKV['envs'] for server in env['lServeurs'] if envsKV['id']=="talend" and env['id']=="DEV" and server['sshServer']=="jardev0"] 

print(targetPorts[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

LINQ style filtering syntax AFAIK is not available unless you can go for list comprehension.

But you can have a method like this

```
def get_ssh_port(id,env_id,ssh_server):

  import json
  ssh_ports= []
  input_dict = json.loads(input_json)
  output_dict = [x for x in input_dict if x['id'] == id]
  for x in output_dict:
    for i in x['envs']:
      if(i['id'] == env_id):
        for j in i['lServeurs']:
           if(j['sshServer']==ssh_server):
              ssh_ports.append(j['sshPort'])
  return ssh_ports
```

**Usage:**

```
input_json = """
[
    {
        "id": "talend",
        "envs":
            [
            {"id":"DEV",
             "lServeurs" :
                 [
                    {"sshServer":"jardev0", "sshPort":"20022","sshUser":"talend"},
                    {"sshServer":"jardev01","sshPort":"20022","sshUser":"talend"}
                 ]
            },
            {"id": "PROD",
             "lServeurs" :
                [
                    {"sshServer": "jardprd01", "sshPort": "20023","sshUser":"talend"}
                ]
            }
            ]
    },
    {
        "id": "eprel",
        "envs":
            [
                {"id": "DEV",
                 "lServeurs" :
                     [
                         {"sshServer": "jardev0",  "sshPort": "20024", "sshUser":"eprel"},
                         {"sshServer": "jardev01", "sshPort": "20025", "sshUser":"eprel"}
                     ]
                 },
                {"id": "PROD",
                 "lServeurs" :
                     [
                         {"sshServer": "jardprd01", "sshPort": "20026","sshUser":"eprel"}
                     ]
                 }
            ]
    }
]
"""

get_ssh_port(id = 'talend',  env_id = 'DEV',  ssh_server = 'jardev0')
```